# verifying recaptcha in php

Tags: php, html, recaptcha, verification

I have a simple .html contact form with recaptcha added to it and I have a correspond .php file set up to send the populated form fields information back to me via my email. After the form has been submitted, I redirect the user to my homepage. I'm trying to figure out what code is needed to add the recaptcha verification to the .php file and where, while still retaining the functionality I already have set up.

html code:

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer>
</script>

<form method="post" action="mail.php">
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Question/Comment" required></textarea>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY SITE KEY"></div>
  <input class="btn-success formBtn" name="submit" type="submit" />
  <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
</form>
```

php code:

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "MY EMAIL";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or 
   die("Error!");
   header('Location: /');

?>
```

Comment: probably a few thousand tutorials on that, here's one: http://acmeextension.com/integrate-google-recaptcha-with-php/

Comment: [Google has documentation on how to implement reCAPTCHA verification using PHP](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php): have you not read it?

Comment: I was able to get a very basic level of working functionality by following this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579265/install-info-for-google-recaptcha-on-contact-form-php-file

Answer (score 0):

your html code seems good, you can try the following php code to see if it works with your form. also make sure you are using the v2 reCaptcha key.

php code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
  $captcha = $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $handle = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&response=$captcha");
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  $explodedArr = explode(",",$response);
  $doubleExplodedArr = explode(":",$explodedArr[0]);
  $captchaConfirmation = end($doubleExplodedArr);

  if(trim($captchaConfirmation) == "true") {

    $to ='example@email.com';
    $subject = 'Form';
    $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $message = '';
    $message .= "<strong>First Name:</strong> " .$_POST['name'] ;
    $message .= "<strong>Email:</strong> " . $_POST['email'];
    $message .= "<strong>Message:</strong> " . $_POST['message'] ; 
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if($send) {
      echo "Message Sent. Thank You!";
    } else {
      echo "<script> alert('Message Not Sent. Please try again.";
    }

  } else {
    echo "Captcha entry was wrong. Please try again.";
  }
} 
?>
```